# How to call activity dynamically depend on situation android?

Tags: android, web-services

Depending on webservice reponse i want to call activity.If response giving more list items then call activity1 ,if response giving only on list item call activity1.I want to decide this one in Home page only.Give me guidance?Presently iam using web service calling in activity1.But instead of that i want to use separate java(without activity)and depending on reponse calling suitable activity.Mean time i dont want to face any blank screen?Hope understand.Please help us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put ProgressDialog in HomePage and get response from server in thread
then forward the activity to which you like.

At time you are calling the second activity dismiss the progressDialog in Homepage.

Try this.

Comment: Already did what you told.But, In home page only we need to decide which page we want to go

Comment: Sorry Now edited it , Just put progressdialog in home activity then handle it. Can you?